# Trying to filter via RxJS data returned via Angular's HttpClient which is returning data from a db table

Tags: angular, rxjs

Takes the Angular Heroes and added a column of rating to it. The ratings contains values like good, very good, poor

Trying to take advantage of RxJS, filter operator to do this. When looking at https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter example 2 
it seems to be what I want

```
// RxJS v6+
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

//emit ({name: 'Joe', age: 31}, {name: 'Bob', age:25})
const source = from([
  { name: 'Joe', age: 31 },
  { name: 'Bob', age: 25 }
]);
//filter out people with age under 30
const example = source.pipe(filter(person => person.age >= 30));
//output: "Over 30: Joe"
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(`Over 30: ${val.name}`));
```

however when using httpclient it does not work and has an error of "**Property 'rating' does not exist on type 'Hero[]'.ts(2339)**"

```
  isVeryGoodAd(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl).pipe(
      filter(heroes => heroes.rating === 'verygood')
      ) 
    ;
  }
```

How to use httpclient with RxJS filter to remove the unwanted values while returning an Observable which I would be able to subscribe to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `filter` operator in the first example is not the same as the `filter` array function.

#### RxJS filter

RxJS `filter` will choose to let an observable value through based on a condition. It is a condition on the whole object.

The first example works because `from` emits each item sequentially, and then the `filter` operates on each item individually, discarding the ones that fail the condition. If you take the filter out, you will see that 2 items arrive in the subscribe method sequentially.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ef3udf

The http request returns one value only. The `filter` is attempting to check a condition against the whole response, and is complaining that the `rating` property doesn't exist on an array (which is exactly what the error message says).

#### Array filter

Array `filter` will return elements in an array matching a condition. It checks a condition for each item in the array.

#### The solution

You are receiving one object from the `HttpClient` - the response. You want to conditionally remove some items. This is a transformation - you start off with an array and return a subset of that array.

For transformations in the pipe you use the RxJS `map` operator (not to be confused with the array function!). You can then apply the `filter` array function inside the RxJS `map`.

```js
isVeryGoodAd(): Observable<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl).pipe(
    map(heroes => heroes.filter(hero => hero.rating === 'verygood'))
  );
}
```